# Unable to build android in IONIC 6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

When I run ionic cordova build android –prod i get the error:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Downloading from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip failed: timeout
```

**I'm behind a proxy**, so I set
ionic config set -g proxy http://proxy-****.****.***:9999

I have executed ionic start myApp tabs --cordova --type=angular
I have executed ionic serve

but i can't do the build

I will be very grateful if you can help me please.

```
Ionic:
Ionic CLI: 6.20.3 
Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 6.3.2
Cordova:
Cordova CLI: 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms: android 10.1.2
Utility:
cordova-res: not installed globally
native-run: not installed globally
System:
NodeJS: v16.17.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm: 8.15.0
OS: Windows 10
```

Comment: Have you tried force building using `Ant`? `ionic cordova build android --prod -- --ant`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you already added `android` in your ionic app then proceed on these steps.

1. Download the gradle: `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip`
2. Place the zip file inside: `{YourAppName}/platforms/android/gradle`
3. Set an environment variable in your OS: `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="../gradle-7.1.1-all.zip"`
4. Run `ionic cordova build android --prod`

Comment: hi

I downloaded the zip.
I put the zip without unpacking in C:\ionic5\test1\platforms\android\gradle

the environment variable (system variable) is
CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL = C:\ionic5\test1\platforms\android\gradle

I have gradle-wrapper.properties file like this. 
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip                              I have modified it but the compilation updates it again to download it.

Comment: The environment variable must be equal to this exactly: `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="../gradle-7.1.1-all.zip"`